# Accordion with Angular

Tags: angularjs, controller, accordion

I'm trying to create a simple accordion with angular. I've come up with this - which works, but the logic is super ugly. Is there a better way to code this?

The accordion opens when a class is applied with ng-class. The difficulty is in making sure only one panel is open at a time. Thanks for reading this post!

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('FooterController', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    return $scope.toggleFooterNav = function(target) {
      $scope.Panel1 = $scope.Panel2 = $scope.Panel3 = $scope.Panel4 = false;
      switch (target) {
        case 'Panel1':
          return $scope.Panel1 = !$scope.Panel1;
        case 'Panel2':
          return $scope.Panel2 = !$scope.Panel2;
        case 'Panel3':
          return $scope.Panel3 = !$scope.Panel3;
        case 'Panel4':
          return $scope.Panel4 = !$scope.Panel4;
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

```css
    .footerNavPanel {
      display: none;
    }
    .footerNavPanelActive {
      display: block !important;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div class="columns" ng-controller="FooterController">
    <h6><a href="#" ng-click="toggleFooterNav('Panel1')">Panel1</a></h6>
    <ul class="footerNavPanel" ng-class="{'footerNavPanelActive' : Panel1}">
      <li><a>Test</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <h6><a href="#" ng-click="toggleFooterNav('Panel2')">Panel2</a></h6>
    <ul class="footerNavPanel" ng-class="{'footerNavPanelActive' : Panel2}">
      <li><a>Test</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <h6><a href="#" ng-click="toggleFooterNav('Panel3')">Panel3</a></h6>
    <ul class="footerNavPanel" ng-class="{'footerNavPanelActive' : Panel3}">
      <li><a>Test</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <h6><a href="#" ng-click="toggleFooterNav('Panel4')">Panel4</a></h6>
    <ul class="footerNavPanel" ng-class="{'footerNavPanelActive' : Panel4}">
      <li><a>Test</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Just figured out the answer, it was much simpler than I thought:

ng-click='activeFooter =  "Panel1"'
ng-class="{'footerNavPanelActive' : activeFooter ===  "Panel1" }")